# How to transform area integral $\int_{D} \omega^2 \ dx \ dy$ into boundary integral $\oint_{C} \square \ ds$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Let $\omega$ be a function that satisfies the Laplace's equation

$$\nabla^2 \omega = 0$$

The values $\omega$ and $\dfrac{\partial \omega}{\partial n}$ are known in the boundary, but not in the interior.

I want to find the value of $I$

$$I = \int_{\Omega} \omega^2 \ dx \ dy$$

### Question

How can I transform the integral $I$ over the plane domain $D$ into a boundary integral over $C$ ?

$$I = \int_{D} \omega^2 \ dx \ dy = \oint_{C} \square \ ds$$

### Motivation

I'm solving laplace's equation by using Boundary Element Method and after find $\omega$, I want some mesures from it.

Basically BEM gives us both values of $\omega$ and $\dfrac{\partial \omega}{\partial n}$ at boundary, then having $I$ in terms of $\omega$ and $\dfrac{\partial \omega}{\partial n}$ is perfect.

I achieved computing for a generic polynomial function $g(x, \ y)$:

> Find an arbitrary function $u(x, \ y)$ such
>
> $$\nabla^2 u = g$$
>
> I can use Green's second identity to get.
>
> $$\int_{D} \omega \cdot g \ dx \ dy = \int_{D} \omega \nabla^2 u - u \nabla^2 \omega \ dx \ dy = \oint_{C} \omega \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n} - u \dfrac{\partial \omega}{\partial n} \ ds$$

Unfortunatelly I don't know how I can proceed for $\omega^2$.
I tried to use $g = \omega$, but finding $u$ such $\nabla^2 u = \omega$ is hard

Comment: You can use the generalized version of Stokes' theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem).

Comment: @Abezhiko I don't see how. From what I know, the Stokes theorem applied on a bidimensional case is only Green's theorem.